# Can't fetch or commit from git

Tags: git, github

First time using bitbucket. A teammate created a repository and added me as a admin user (both read/write access). It says that am not authorized:

https://alexoh86@bitbucket.org/margaretmz/language-app-angelhack.git: not authorized

There was a time when I was able to fetch and commit (but no changed showed up in the repository when I committed, and none of the files updated when I did a fetch). No idea how that happened. The not authorized error message showed up again later.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

EDIT: Should mention that I am using the Eclipse plugin to commit/fetch from repo.

Comment: Have you talked to the teammate about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the repository is on github, not bitbucket.  That's probably why you're having problems.  There is no user named margaretmz on bitbucket, nor any project named language-app.

Looks like the correct URL is:

https://github.com/margaretmz/language-app

though there's nothing currently in it.

Comment: don't know much about bitbucket, but I do know that the project is private. Should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: Going to be hard to help without seeing details, logs, etc.  I'd suggest you contact the team member with the account for help.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. My only solution was to restart the computer.